# How to show that $\dim\left(\operatorname {Im}A\right)=\dim\left(\operatorname {Im}A^*\right)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $A:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map and $A^*:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be the adjoint of $A$ (that's $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,A^*y\rangle$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^m,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$).

I know ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449879/ax-b-leftrightarrow-b-in-left-ker-a-right-perp)) that $b\in\operatorname {Im}A$ if, and only if, $\langle b,z\rangle=0$ for all $z\in\operatorname {Ker} A^* $.

But the problem asks to conclude that $\dim\left(\operatorname {Im}A\right)=\dim\left(\operatorname {Im}A^*\right)$. How can I do this? Is it obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you remember the rank formula? How are $\dim \ker f$, $\dim \operatorname{im} f$ and $\dim V$ related?

Comment: In this case $m=\dim\mathbb{R}^m=\dim\left(\text{Im}A\right)+\dim\left(\text{Ker}A\right)$ and $n=\dim\mathbb{R}^n=\dim\left(\text{Im}A^*\right)+\dim\left(\text{Ker}A^*\right)$

Comment: Right. I'm interested in the second case, $\dim \operatorname{Im} A^\ast = n - \dim \ker A^\ast$. Do you know another space with dimension $n - \dim \ker A^\ast$?

Comment: Since $\dim (\text{Im}A)^\perp=n-\dim (\text{Im}A)$ and $\text{Ker}A^*=(\text{Im}A)^\perp$ we conclude that $n-\dim(\text{Ker}A^*)=n-\dim (\text{Im}A)^\perp=\dim(\text{Im}A)$

Comment: Yup. Though I thought we'd go $n - \dim \ker A^\ast = \dim (\ker A^\ast)^\perp = \dim \operatorname{Im} A$.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to pick an orthonormal basis, and write down the matrices of $A$ and of $A^*$. One is the transpose of the other, so they have the same rank.